# conditionally import CSS files based on data-attribute in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have two large autogenerated CSS files **dark-theme.css** and **light-theme.css**

I want to conditionally import them using a data attribute "data-theme"

So I tried this in my "theme.scss" file

```
:root,
[data-theme="light"] {
  @import url('light-theme.css');
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  @import url('dark-theme.css');
}
```

This does not work and it always loads the rules only from the dark theme even if "data-theme" has changed to light

**NOTE** The two CSS files have the exact same classes and rules except that the color is changed. These files are externally autogenerated and large and it is tedious to manually change them so I would prefer a conditional way of overriding the stylesheet based on the data attribute.

Comment: Use [sass's `@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) rather than css's

Comment: Also, you might look into using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for color theming.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can just import it without the `.css` extension.

But it then won't get lazy loaded